# Routing and Remote Access Service won't start after full disk

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rras, accounting

The HDD of the server was out of disk space, and after a reboot, RRAS won't start anymore on my 2008 R2 server.

Error Details:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        RemoteAccess
Date:          2/5/2012 9:39:52 PM
Event ID:      20153
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Windows14111.<snip>
Description:
The currently configured accounting provider failed to load and initialize successfully. The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="RemoteAccess" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">20153</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-02-05T20:39:52.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>12148869</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Windows14111.<snip></Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error.</Data>
    <Binary>2C030000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I think it has something to do with a corrupt config file, but I am unsure of what to do. I Removed the RRAS role, rebooted, and re-added, but it keeps failing with the same error.

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

If i set the accounting provider from 'Windows' to '' the service starts but VPN won't work. Any ideas how this can be repaired?

Comment: Typical sources of help are [eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=20153&eventno=2104&source=RemoteAccess&phase=1) and [Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=20153&EvtSrc=RemoteAccess) - have you seen those and checked the hints against your settings?

Comment: Changed the loggin directory to a different disk that has plenty of space, but it din't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sneaking suspicion that your Network Policy Server (NPS) configuration was damaged during your disk-full situation. If you can handle rebuilding your NPS configuration you might try doing an `netsh nps reset config` to reset the configuration back to stock. If this doesn't work you might try replacing %SystemRoot%\System32\IAS\IAS.XML with a stock IAS.XML file. In either case you'll have to re-create your NPS policies.

Comment: I tried the netsh reset to no avail. The IAS.xml file exists and seems complete; is there anything I can do? The only reason I use RRAS is for VPN; back when I configured it, I only added the role and set the IP range; I already tried removing and re-adding the role, but no dice. Are there any other steps I can take?